# react write file: nothing works (fs, file-system...)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend, fs

I'm trying to write to a file on the server side, using react with create-react-app.

First I tried to use the **fs** module, with the following code (copy-pasted from the doc, except the console log):

```
const fs = require('fs');
console.log("fs=",fs);
fs.writeFile('acme.js', 'console.log("hello")', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('New file acme.js is either created or if exists then updated');
});
```

The fs object exists, but I get the error **TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function**

Then tried to use the **file-system** module. Here's what I entered:

```
var fs = require('file-system');
fs.writeFile('path/test.txt', 'aaa', function(err) {"error error"})
```

Then I get the error **TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function**

I also tried a github repository at https://github.com/hurkanyakay/reactjs-nodejs-rest-example whose description looked like what I am trying to do. I get messages when executing the commands suggested on the Frontend, specifically **Error: Can't resolve 'glamor/lib/hash'** .

There appear to be existing issues on these repositories, I have added the detailed error messages there.

I'm using Windows 10 1803, npm v6.4.1, node v8.12.0

I'm wondering whether there isn't something I've missed, maybe my understanding is lacking? Am I using the wrong modules? Is it just that what I'm trying to do can't be done?

Comment: could you give some more context? Where is this piece of code in your app? What runs it?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure: your first example is a `.js` file you are running with node, right?

From your command prompt, try:

```
> node -pe 'require("fs").writeFile'
```

You should receive the output:

```
[Function]
```

Then try:

```
> node -e 'require("fs").writeFileSync("hello.txt", "Hello World", "utf8")'
```

This should create the file `hello.txt`.

If those work, then take your first example program, put it in a file called `example.js`, and run it with:

```
> node example.js
```

If these commands don't work correctly, you may have something seriously broken in your node install -- I'd suggest uninstalling completely and starting over.

Comment: Suggested commands give errors. I then removed + reinstalled nodejs as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows 

Error remains, here is the dialog:

C:\Users\fvila>node -pe 'require("fs").writeFile'
require(fs).writeFile

Comment: C:\Users\fvila>node -e 'require("fs").writeFileSync("hello.txt", "Hello World", "utf8")'
[eval]:1
'require(fs).writeFileSync(hello.txt,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:587:27)
...

Comment: Sorry responses are scrambled in comments. Anyway, I've unistalled / reinstalled nodejs, version is now 1.15.0, the commands you suggest still give errors. It stops at the comma after "hello.txt"

Comment: If you run `node --version`, what's the exact output? Also, this thread reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337252/file-system-nodejs-uncaught-typeerror-fs-writefilesync-is-not-a-function?rq=1 -- is it possible you are trying to run this code _in a browser?_ If so, be aware that `fs` is not available in the browser.

Comment: 1) "In a browser?": It's in React, it's a web app, so yes, the error does appear in the browser. 2) I believe the solution suggested in the link will save the file on the client side? Is there any way of saving on the server side? I want multiple contributors to edit the content of a data file.

Comment: Reading further into the matter, I'm gathering that to write into a server file from a react web application, you need: 1) a server module such as Express, to respond to server requests, 2) an API module such as Axios, to make those calls from the web application.  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-file-upload-with-react-and-node-2aa3f9aab3f0 seems to describe this, from the angle of uploading files.

Comment: Exactly right.  Most web applications that have any kind of state (like user logins, shared files, etc.) have both a _front-end_ and a _back-end_.  The front-end is what the user sees in the browser (a "React app" is an example of a front-end).  The back-end, which can be Express, is what would run in node.js.  The front-end then talks to the back-end as the user uses the application, and the back-end may read/write files on a server, save records in a database like MySQL, etc.

Comment: I'd try starting with just building the basic Express server first as your back-end, see article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0.

Comment: The link to https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0 looks like the best answer I've seen to this specific problem, thanks @elliotnelson, I'll check it out.